# Why icon "car" cannot move following "path" in svg?

Tags: reactjs, svg, use-effect, use-state

[image]

after click "next" the path change color but "car" cannot move

[image]

when I setState

[image].

But if setState in

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState('here!!! I set positon')
```

car move. What is the problem ???

full code. Sorry I cannot add code here

[image: handle function]
[image: file svg]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You'll get more help if you edit your question and add the code directly to it (as text). That way we can easily read and copy/paste your code into our answers.

Comment: I believe I see the issue and have answered below, but please do edit your question to include properly formatted code snippets. Images are nice, but they are not searchable, not copy/paste-able, and can be more difficult to read.

Comment: Hello, checking in if my answer has helped address/resolve your question/issue.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are mutating your state in `PathMove` function. `clone` ***is not actually*** a clone of the `array`, but rather just a shallow copy of it. All the elements in the array are references to the elements in the original array.

```
const PathMove = value => {
  const clone = [...array];
  const index = clone.findIndex(x => x.id === value);
  for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    clone[i].status = true; // <-- state mutation!!
  }
  return setArray(clone);
};
```

## Solution

Along with shallow copying the array, you need to shallow copy all elements and nested state that you are updating. In this case it seems you are updating them all.

Here I'm using a functional state update to update from the previous state (*not the state enclosed in the callback*). Shallow copy the array and then also shallow copy the elements being updated.

```
const PathMove = value => {
  setArray(array => {
    const index = array.findIndex(x => x.id === value);

    return array.map((el, i) => i < index ? {
      ...el,        // <-- shallow copy element
      status: true, // <-- update status property
    } : el);
  });
};
```